# How to combine cobra and klog

Tags: go, go-cobra, klog

I have a project that needs to use `cobra` and `klog` to generate executable and print logs and keep.

Firstly, I tested that using the following `klog` can output the log to the `terminal and file` at the same time.

```
package main
import (
    "flag"
    "k8s.io/klog"
)
func init() {
    var fs flag.FlagSet
    klog.InitFlags(&fs)
    fs.Set("logtostderr", "false")
    fs.Set("log_file_max_size", "100")
    fs.Set("log_file", "/home/test/workspace/klogfile/test.log")
    fs.Set("alsologtostderr", "true")
}
func main() {
    defer klog.Flush()
    klog.Info("info")
    klog.Warning("warning")
    klog.Error("error")
}
```

The content of file `/home/test/workspace/klogfile/test.log` is as follow

```
Log file created at: 2023/04/06 16:46:07
Running on machine: s52
Binary: Built with gc go1.16.12 for linux/amd64
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0406 16:46:07.751183   13512 main.go:20] info
W0406 16:46:07.751594   13512 main.go:21] warning
E0406 16:46:07.751629   13512 main.go:22] error
```

Then I try to add it to `cobra` based on `k8s style`

```
package main
import (
    "flag"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "k8s.io/klog"
)
var (
    str = "hello world"
)
func NewCommand() *cobra.Command {
    cmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "echo",
        Short: "use klog with cobra",
        Long:  "Use klog together with cobra.",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            Run()
        },
    }
    klog.InitFlags(flag.CommandLine)
    cmd.Flags().AddGoFlagSet(flag.CommandLine)
    cmd.Flags().SortFlags = false
    cmd.Flags().StringVar(&str, "str", str, "string to print")
    return cmd
}
func Run() {
    defer klog.Flush()
    klog.Infof("Running, str:%s", str)
}

func main() {
    if err := NewCommand().Execute(); err != nil {
        klog.Fatalf("root cmd execute failed, err=%v", err)
    }
}
```

I can print out the `required log options` through `--help`, but when I override them to achieve the save to file in the above example, **only the output is output to the terminal and not to the file**

```
# go run main2.go --logtostderr false --log_file_max_size "100" --alsologtostderr true --log_file "/home/test/workspace/klogfile/test2.log"
I0406 16:52:57.479455   15217 cobra_klog.go:34] Running, str:hello world
```

May I ask where I am `missing the necessary code`, if so, please let me know how to modify it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code. The only issue is that you must use the `-flag=false` form to turn off a boolean flag (see [Command line flag syntax](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#hdr-Command_line_flag_syntax)).

Try this command (repalce `--logtostderr false` with `--logtostderr=false`):

```
go run main2.go --logtostderr=false --log_file_max_size "100" --alsologtostderr true --log_file "/home/test/workspace/klogfile/test2.log"
```

BTW, I think `--log_file_max_size "100"` could be simplified to `--log_file_max_size 100`.

---

**Update**:

To reduce the exposed flags of klog:

```
 package main
 
 import (
    "flag"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "k8s.io/klog"
 )
 
 var (
    str     = "hello world"
+   logFile string
 )
 
 func NewCommand() *cobra.Command {
+   var fs flag.FlagSet
+   klog.InitFlags(&fs)

    cmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "echo",
        Short: "use klog with cobra",
        Long:  "Use klog together with cobra.",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
+           fs.Set("logtostderr", "false")
+           fs.Set("log_file", logFile)

            Run()
        },
    }
-   klog.InitFlags(flag.CommandLine)
-   cmd.Flags().AddGoFlagSet(flag.CommandLine)
    cmd.Flags().SortFlags = false
    cmd.Flags().StringVar(&str, "str", str, "string to print")
+   cmd.Flags().StringVar(&logFile, "log_file", "", "If non-empty, use this log file")
    return cmd
 }
 func Run() {
    defer klog.Flush()
    klog.Infof("Running, str:%s", str)
 }
 
 func main() {
    if err := NewCommand().Execute(); err != nil {
        klog.Fatalf("root cmd execute failed, err=%v", err)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I would like to ask again. I want to simplify the exposed parameters. Only the `--log_file` configuration and `--str` parameters are exposed. Others are directly set to default, such as `--logtostderr=false`. How can I modify it to be appropriate?

Comment: In fact, the workaround is in your first example. See the demo in the updated answer.